# How to use Command.CanExecute from a child control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, command

Here is the setup (extraneous layout code removed):

Window.xaml

```
<Button Name="btn_Next" Command="NextPage">Next</Button>
<ContentControl Name="contentControl1" >
        <Binding ElementName="MainWindow" Path="CurrentPage"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Window.xaml.cs Constructor

```
  var nextCommand = new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.NextPage);
  nextCommand.CanExecute += nextCommand_CanExecute;
  nextCommand.Executed += nextCommand_Executed;
  CommandBindings.Add(nextCommand);
```

This works great in the base example, where `nextCommand_CanExecute` checks if the CurrentPage is the last page. However, that logic is currently just checking an array and only works for linear navigation. However, the navigation is going to be tree-like and this will not work, where the items in the `contentControl1` will sometimes branch in different directions. So, I would like to have the user control that is the `CurrentPage` have the opportunity to override the `CanExecute`. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the `UserControl` to start the `CanExecute`. I have tried to use a number of `CommandTarget` settings to no avail...my child control never has it's `CanExecute` method triggered. I have even tried to use the `e.ContinueRouting = true` in the parent window's CanExecute. Here is the User Control code in case that helps.

User Control Constrtuctor:

```
  var nextCommand = new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.NextPage);
  nextCommand.CanExecute += nextCommand_CanExecute;
  CommandBindings.Add(nextCommand);
```

User Control CanExecute method:

```
private void nextCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.CanExecute = false;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routed command events tunnel from the root of the visual tree down to the control that initiated them, and then bubble back up. Josh Smith's article on routed commands has a good write-up of how it works (see the "Routed" section in particular) http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/.

The issue here is that your user control (inside of the content control), is not an "ancestor" of the button which issues the command, so the routed event never reaches it (even in passing). Given the way your visual tree is structured, I don't think routed commands are going to be enough for you.

The first solution that comes to mind is rigging up your own mechanism for delegating CanExecute/Executed logic to your user controls. Maybe you could define a base class or interface that is implemented by all such controls which defines the various command CanExecute/Executed methods that are needed. Then you can just have a top-level implementation which casts the currently loaded control off as your interface/base class type and call the appropriate method.

Comment: Darn, that is what I was thinking I might have to do...and was hoping there was something already built-in

Comment: I think the only way to get the built-in thing to work would be to house the navigation buttons inside of the user control, which doesn't look like it would work for you.